# how to produce jet color in 2d scatterplot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Basically, I have been trying to create a jet colored scatter plot in MATLAB.
[image]

Ref: Clayson et al. 2013

I have no z-value. Colormap is also not working. How exactly to do it? Thanks

Comment: It's a good type of plot, but please, please, please use a better color map. Jet is terrible for many reasons (google "rainbow color map considered harmful" to learn more). It has taken MATLAB 20 years to change their default color map from jet to the much better parula. Please don't perpetuate the bad jet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a density scatter plot. You don't need a third dimension in order to create it, so don't worry for your missing `z`. The coloring algorithm is based on the density of the points.

Such plotting function is not included in the default Matlab packages and toolboxes, but after a quick search I probably found exactly what you are looking for. Take a look at [this File Exchange release](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8430-flow-cytometry-data-reader-and-visualization?focused=6779485&tab=example). It contains a full working function for creating density scatters together with a few illustrated usage examples:

[image: DSCATTER]

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying gscatter though.